# Can google misuse important information from my documents?

Tags: security, google

As mentioned in google [policies](http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/) google reads your all document to improve their search and suggestion. But If I keep some important document on google drive, like : new business ideas, innovation papers, personal letters or password, can they really misuse that information?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: In short - yes they can but no, they wont.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Google privacy policy](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/) which explains what rights google have to your data (tl;dr: they have the right to access everything you upload to them).

Comment: Which, *technically*, means they can't steal something that you *gave* them voluntarily.

Comment: If you really, *really* need security, use pencil and paper.

Comment: @Joe L.: And if you really, really, really need security, don't even write it down :-)

Comment: @Oddthinking, it is defined in their policies that they use user's data to refine their analysis and to give improved suggestions. So it is not my speculation.

Comment: @Piskvor, you are correct, steal is not the proper word here to use. Should I say, can they use my ideas?

Comment: Great. Please link to a claim they make, and quote it, and we can address whether that claim is true. A clause in a contract is rarely a claim though.

Comment: You might ask this question on [Web Applications SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @Oddthinking, updated the question.

Comment: @sumelic, as per their policy they are technically capable to do it. and they do it. My question is more about can they misuse that information? I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: What does 'can' mean, if you acknowledge they are technically capable? What would a No answer look like?

Comment: (Which isn't the biggest problem. What is the claim?)